# Word Reading CustomXmlParts gets stuck intermittently

Tags: office-addins, office-js

Env: Mac Office 2016 build 15.26

I'm reading the Word documents' CustomXmlParts after Office.initialize is finished. I'm using the Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync API. The getByNamespaceAsync gets stuck intermittently. As soon as I click in the Word document, the API resumes and reads CustomXmlParts successfully.

Any work around this? I also tried to call context.document.getSelection to mimic cursor click, but did not help.

```
Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync("MyXmlTag", function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.value.length > 0) {
                                asyncResult.value[0].getNodesAsync("/", function (asyncNodeResult) {
                                    if (asyncNodeResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                        console.log(" Failed to read word document.  " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));

                                   } else {
                                        asyncNodeResult.value[0].getNodeValueAsync(function (result) {
                                            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                                                console.log(" getNodeValueAsync: Failed " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                //result.valuse is xml data
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log(" CustomXML part is not found");
                            }
                        });
```

`

Comment: thanks for reporting this issue. we are actively investigating and provide outcomes soon. btw do you have a sample XML used for this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. I haven't been able to reproduce it internally. Some questions:

- When you say that you run this code "after Office.initialize is finished", do you mean that it is inside your Office.initialize callback code (and also inside $(document).ready, so that it executes after the HTML/JS is finished loading), or is it in completely separate code? How is your code triggered?
- Does the issue occur in all custom XML you have tried, or just specific custom XML?

Comment: It's outside office.initialize.

Comment: It's outside office.initialize. From one of my angular state, I poll for a flag that gets set in          Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {  MyGlobal.officeInitialized = true}); }     This issue does not seem to be specific to custom XML. My add-in makes a bunch of word api calls throughout its lifecycle. I've also noticed very rarely that create content control api (context.sync) also gets stuck. When I click on the document, the content control appears on the document.

Comment: It looks like the Word application goes into kind of hibernation mode when left unused for a longer time. 
Try this to reproduce:
1. Load add-in
2. Keep Word app open, and do not use it for a while (may be 15+ or 30+ minutes)
3. Reload add-in (do not click anywhere else in Word document. Mostly I notice cursor on the Word document is not blinking, just displays frozen | )
4. The API gets stuck
5. Click in the Word document area. (The cursor starts blinking)
6. The API resumes.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information. We understand the issue and we're working on fixing it.

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey.  Any idea when will the fix be available?

Comment: Hi Pankaj, we improved support for APIs that run without user input in Word, in the latest Word release (15.29), which is currently available in Insider Slow preview. Let me know if you continue to see your issue beyond that release. Thanks!

Comment: We have a similar problem with Word for windows 16.0.7426.1015. Is there a corresponding release for windows?